# Best practice for CSS dynamic sized button with gradient and arrow

Tags: html, css, button, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Zurb Foundation framework and I'm trying to make some call-to-action buttons which are dynamic in size with text, a background gradient and a right pointing arrow.

I can think of three possible ways to do this :

1. Have an a element wrap another element and style both backgrounds such that one has the gradient and the other has the arrow positioned on the right.
2. Have just an a element with a gradient background and put the arrow as an img in my html.
3. Use one element with one background image including the gradient and arrow for the whole thing.

Each of these options feels wrong in some way -

1. I have a non-semantic div purely for style purposes.
2. I have an img in my html even though it is purely stylistic.
3. Feels like a dirty solution, especially if the button is scalable.

What is the best practice of these options, or is there a method I haven't considered ? How do I also ensure the button scales nicely with the text and arrow in the right places as the Zurb Columns scale ?

Muchos gracias ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly but if you are using Foundation then have you tried:

```
<div class="side-buttons">
    <button id="someid" class="nice [red:green:blue:black] button" onclick="someEvent();"/>
</div>
```

The nice class adds a gradient similar to what I believe you are talking about. And the side-buttons class, if I remember correctly, keeps the button width inherited, i.e. from a nested div with class "two columns", but the height adjusts depending on the text.

Hope I have helped, maybe you could post some code with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox and Webkit, you can use CSS3 multiple background syntax to apply both a gradient and background image via css.

```
.gradAndImg {
    background-image: url(image.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffcc00, #ffffff);
    background-image: url(image.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left-top, left-bottom, from(#ffcc00), to(#ffffff));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but surely targeting just those browsers isn't a good solution ? I was looking for a best practice...